# jQuery .load in closest span instead of element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a script that loads fetched data into a span within an anchor.

The Link:

```
<a id="dbobject" tdbid="1">Weapon of mass destruction<span>fetch content goes here</span></a>
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[tdbid]').each(function(){

            $(this).load('data/fetch.php?id='+ $(this).attr('tdbid'), function(){
            });
            });
        });
```

The content is getting loaded into the span perfectly, When you hover the link it shows the span with the content in it. But I rather have the span outside of the link so when you mouse off the anchor the window disappears,

Now when you hover over it you can also position your mouse within the span which is really not user friendly if there are more links underneath that link.

I tried doing:

The Link:

```
<a id="dbobject" tdbid="1">Weapon of mass destruction</a><span>fetch content goes here</span>
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[tdbid]').each(function(){

            $(this).closest('span').load('data/fetch.php?id='+ $(this).attr('tdbid'), function(){
            });
            });
        });
```

Which isn't working. But while making that I thought, If I want to show that span on hover than I'd have to set the span default to hidden. So a span throughout the page without the link will also be hidden, Which is not what I intend to do.

So How can I make my hover to show a div with the fetched content inside?

Comment: We have no idea where this span is, what `this` is, or what you're talking  about, how about posting the HTML ?

Comment: I've updated the code, My apologies it's indeed not clear what I originally posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `<span>` after `<a>` use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[tdbid] + span').each(function(){

            $(this).load('data/fetch.php?id='+ $(this).attr('tdbid'), function(){
            });
            });
        });
```

"closest" returns the closest *ancestor*. What you need here is the next *sibling*.